# What would be the way to use keycloack without opening a web browser page?

Tags: java, swing, authentication, keycloak

I am trying to build a desktop app and a cli app that will use keycloack as backend to manage users.

I would like how can I perform a login action on the keycloack server. I found the Keycloak Installed Application library, but for a desktop app it will open the default web browser, and for a cli it will ask to open a given url.

Is there a way for me to provides login and password from a custom swing component (or keyboard input read for the the cli) without having this web browser page displayed ?

Do I have to use something like and open id 2.0 or saml library ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keycloak uses the open id connect (OIDC) protocol. OIDC is an authentication extension to the OAuth2.0 Protocol. OAuth uses a few specified flows for obtaining tokens. The most common ones, and the most secure ones are the Auth code flow and the Implicit flow. Keycloak uses a hybrid of these flows for its browser based authentication. If you wanted to login without the use of a browser you can use the Resource Owner Credential Grant defined in OAuth2.0, its named Direct Grant in keycloak.

Simply enable the direct grant option in your client tab in keycloak, and send a request to the token endpoint with the `grant_type` param as `password`

[Example Post Request](https://prnt.sc/pau4wt)

Comment: Ok, so it is possible, now I am very new to openid / oauth protocol, could you lead me to a sample code ? Could this permit me to fetch the roles of a user if the login is successful ? I will gladly accept your answer.

Comment: Please, could you expand this:  `Keycloak uses a hybrid of these flows for its browser based authentication`?

Comment: I added a screenshot of a post request you'd use to login to keycloak using the direct grant. Remember that you have to enable the direct grant from your client's tab in the keycloak admin console.

Comment: This is a simple rest httpS request ?

Comment: The hybrid flow is an OIDC specific flow that combines some aspects of both Auth Code flow and Implicit flow. You can read the official documentation [here](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#HybridFlowAuth)

Comment: Yes the linked screenshot is a simple post request to the token endpoint of keycloak

Comment: Thanks, @KareemYasser. However, the docs say that even keycloak supports either authorization code flow and hybrid flows, the default one is the authorization code flow, at least in the JS adapter. The hybrid flow must be enabled by configuration: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_javascript_implicit_flow

Comment: Seems im a bit rusty, Keycloak does use Auth Code flow as its default browser flow like you said. Thanks for pointing that out.